# Macros work but shortcuts don't - application.onkey

Tags: excel, vba

I have several macros that work using the following commands:

```
Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.OnKey "^+{Q}", "Load_Theme"
Application.OnKey "^+{W}", "Table_Headings"
Application.OnKey "^+{E}", "Table_Rows_Green"
Application.OnKey "^+{R}", "Table_Rows_Darker_Green"
Application.OnKey "^+{T}", "Table_Rows_Blue"
Application.OnKey "^+{A}", "Autofill_To_The_Right"
Application.OnKey "^+{S}", "Increase_Decimal"
Application.OnKey "^+{D}", "Decrease_Decimal"
Application.OnKey "^+{Z}", "Auto_Colour_Numbers"
Application.OnKey "^+{X}", "Number_Format_Cycle"
Application.OnKey "^+{C}", "Flip_Sign"
Application.OnKey "^+{V}", "Divide_by_1000"
Application.OnKey "^+{B}", "Autofit_Column"
Application.OnKey "^+{\}", "IF_Error_Wrap"
End Sub

Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(cancel As Boolean)
Application.OnKey "^+{Q}"
Application.OnKey "^+{W}"
Application.OnKey "^+{E}"
Application.OnKey "^+{R}"
Application.OnKey "^+{T}"
Application.OnKey "^+{A}"
Application.OnKey "^+{S}"
Application.OnKey "^+{D}"
Application.OnKey "^+{Z}"
Application.OnKey "^+{X}"
Application.OnKey "^+{C}"
Application.OnKey "^+{V}"
Application.OnKey "^+{B}"
Application.OnKey "^+{\}"
End Sub
```

When I copy the module code and the Worksheet code (the one above) into someone else's VBA, the the macros work (by individually selecting them using alt + F8), but the shortcuts don't work (even though they do on my computer).

Is there something wrong with the code or are there Excel settings that might be impeding the other computer?

The module code is in "Module 1" and the code I've posted above is in "ThisWorkbook".

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRnl9.png]

Comment: Are both computers using the same version of Excel? Have you tried the code on a computer using the same version of Excel in which the code was written?

Comment: One, and only one, of my team cannot use the shortcuts for an Excel tool we share.  We found that an enterprise software that only he needed had hijacked the shortcuts.  Check if these shortcuts do something on their computer when Excel is not open.

Comment: Is the other Excel with enabled macros? Or with disabled ones?

Comment: Hi Mistella, not sure if the excel is the same but the macros work so i don't see why it shouldn't work

Comment: Hi Rey, that's a good point I'll give it a go

Comment: Hi Vityata, yes they're enabled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like there are other shortcuts that have overwritten your listed ones, it might be from software that your colleague has but you don't?

It could be a data source provider e.g. bloomberg